# Why need to use past tense in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

This is the sentence I found it in one of the sentence.
From the user's perspective:
"I am a young working professional trying to eat healthily, but I'm struggling because I work long hours and don't always have time to go grocery shopping and prepare my meals. This makes me feel frustrated and bad about myself"

I am wondering why the "frustrated" here needs to use in past tense form and not in infinitive form??

Comment: Frustrated is an adjective here, not a verb in the past.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much